# Is there a windows library equivalent to " it.sephiroth.android.library "

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I am trying to implement `Horizontal ListView`
which was originally from `ios` app using  `it.sephiroth.android.library` into a `Windows 8.1` store app . Is there an equivalent for this android library in windows?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an Horizontal ListView on Windows Apps ?
You can use a ListView and change its ItemsPanel to set up an horizontal panel:

```
<ListView>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
```

There are different kinds of Panel you can use, depending of your needs (VirtualizingStackPanel, ItemsWrapGrid, etc.)

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and get back to you.